# What is the relationship bewteen the version of dll in GAC and the project

Tags: c#, dll

[image]

Let's say, we have a utility library called M.dll, and this one is built on framwork 4.0. And now we want to install it to GAC. Becasue it is based on 4.0, it will install to GAC in the dll group of framework 4.0.

Now we have a project in framwork 3.5, and I assume, all its reference dll files from GAC, is from the dll group of 3.5, so if it want to add reference to M.dll, it will not find this dll, becasue all the dlls from the dialog in VS, as shown below, is from dll groups of 3.5.

Am a right? Is there a concept of dll file group for differnt framwork versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about grouping in framework versions.

GAC allows you to install one or more versions of the same assembly (i.e. `1.0.0.0` and `1.1.0.0`).

It has nothing to do with the target .NET Framework version. You may define what's the minimum framework version during compilation because you've configured a concrete version in your Visual Studio project's properties.

If you try to reference an assembly version which is compiled for a greater version of one of currently installed framework versions, and also your Visual Studio project is configured for an earlier framework version, either you won't see the assembly or if you manage to add it as reference to the project, you'll get compile-time and/or run-time errors (f.e. missing types).

In the other hand, if greater or lower versions of the GAC'd assembly is compiled for currently configured framework version or earlier ones, you'll be able to reference one of them, since newer framework versions are backwards-compatible with earlier ones (there're some exceptions, because some types might be obsolete/deprecated starting from some framework version...).

Comment: Hi, Matias. For example, in .NET 1.0 we have the assembly system.dll, and in .NET 4.0, we still have the assembly system.dll. When we are referring the assembly in VS with project in framewrok 1.0 and project in framework 4.0. Are the two projects referring to the same exact dll file?

Comment: @SunRobin No: they're referencing a assembly called `System.dll` and an exact version compiled for some .NET version

Comment: @SunRobin I mean, System.dll ".NET 1.0" isn't the same as System.dll ".NET 4.0".